# How can I determine why my Java application refuses to terminate cleanly?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I've discovered that under certain circumstances, the JVM will not terminate when I close my JavaFX desktop application window. I am forced to kill the process from within IntelliJ IDEA.

Are there any tools or procedures that I can use to determine what is holding up the application? I tried looking at running threads from within the debug view, but didn't see anything obvious.

I see the following threads running:

```
"pool-4-thread-1@5149" prio=5 tid=0x19 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-3-thread-1@5126" prio=5 tid=0x18 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Prism Font Disposer@3380" daemon prio=10 tid=0x16 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
      at com.sun.javafx.font.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:93)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-1@800" daemon prio=5 tid=0x10 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:492)
      at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:108)

"AWT-Windows@5905" daemon prio=6 tid=0x1c nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(WToolkit.java:-1)
      at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:306)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Java2D Disposer@5290" daemon prio=10 tid=0x1a nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
      at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:148)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Finalizer@428" daemon prio=8 tid=0x3 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
      at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler@429" daemon prio=10 tid=0x2 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)

"DestroyJavaVM@6048" prio=5 tid=0x1f nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Thread-2@900" daemon prio=5 tid=0x12 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener@426" daemon prio=5 tid=0x5 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher@427" daemon prio=9 tid=0x4 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

Comment: JVisualVM comes with the jdk I believe and it can be used to profile java applications. You can see a log of the classes / methods executed after you close the application window. https://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html

Comment: Looks like you have tasks waiting. Perhaps in a loop. Did you forget to call ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown()? Or are you ignoring any InteruptedExceptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JVM will terminate when the only user threads left running are *daemon* threads. Looking at your thread dump we can see two threads that are not daemon threads that are still running:

```
"pool-4-thread-1@5149" prio=5 tid=0x19 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
      ...

"pool-3-thread-1@5126" prio=5 tid=0x18 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
      ...
```

These threads prevent your JVM from terminating.

Judging by the names they are probably spawned from a thread pool in your code. Since they are waiting, they are just idle threads in your pool. There are a couple of options to ensure these threads do not prevent the JVM from terminating:

1. Calling `shutdown()` on your thread pool (or `Executor` or whatever interface you are using).
2. Creating the thread pool with your own thread factory that sets the threads to *daemon* threads.
3. Configuring the thread pool to allow threads to time out and be destroyed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You have two non daemon threads holding your JVM (pool-4-thread-1@5149 & pool-3-thread-1@5126).

Check if the threads your application starts are flagged as daemon threads (with the Thread.setDaemon(true) method). Any non daemon thread still active when your main application thread ends will prevent the application from terminating.

The default threadfactory for executors ensures the threads are not daemon threads. From the names of the threads, they look like they were created by an executor.

So basically check if you have an executor you forgot to shutdown, or a library you use which creates one and for which you forgot to do some cleanup before leaving your main which prevented it from shutting down its executors.